# Remove just last instance of an activity from stack

Tags: android, callstack, object-lifetime

I have an application with 2 activities A and B, A is the main activity and B is called by A but also can be called from B itself.

So my stack will look like

> A,B0,B1,B2,B3

In certain cases I want to be able to remove only last instance of B, so  `[android:noHistory="true"]`  won't work.

> A,B0,B1,B2,B3 =>  A,B0,B1,B2,B4

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below lines will finish the activity in which you are working and will start the same activity:

```
 finish();
 startActivity(getIntent());
```